# Android service context error

Tags: java, android, request, android-volley

I'm trying to build a service that continuously sends http requests with Volley:

```
public class inviadati extends Service {
```

I read that Service is a context, so I should use "this" to refer to it like this

```
public inviadati() {
        RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

But I keep getting a NullPointerException on the RequestQueue line. Any thoughts?

P.S I already tried getApplicationContext(), getActivity(), getBaseContext() but none of them worked.

Comment: Post complete code and log

Answer (score 0):

You are implementing a constructor. You should not do that for a `Service`. Instead, override the `onCreate` method and put your code over there, like this

```
public class inviadati extends Service {

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but then how do I access the queue if the variable is accessible only in onCreate()?

Comment: You need to make it a member, I will update my code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Add this code and change service class name Inviadati

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Service onStartCommand");

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (; ; ) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000 * 60 * 2); // every 2 minuts this service send data
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

                RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            }
        }
    }).start();

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```